# Allow admins to publish html via Windows Live Writer and/or Word

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, publish, windows-live-writer

Currently I have a WYSIWYG editor for admins to post HTML pages on an MVC3 website (with forms authentication.) However I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=c7uLIuMOc_c#t=287s) (~4:45 mins in, if it doesn't take you there,) where a person is able to publish to the MVC3 site by clicking the publish button on Windows Live Writer (and maybe Word, but I don't have either to confirm or play around with;) and everything was published quite easily.

I looked into this cool feature of these programs, but wasn't able to find any information on how to implement it on an MVC3 website. I saw some info on how to use this with Blogger or WordPress, but not MVC (it doesn't help that I don't have either Live Writer or Word on my windows system.)

So I'm asking if anyone knows how to do this, can you point me to a tutorial about this Windows editor feature and how to use it in an MVC3 program? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, courtesy of Scott Hanselman.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode55NotABlogALocalXMLRPCMetaWebLogEndpointThatLiesToWindowsLiveWriter.aspx